# Rotated element becomes blurred when :before underline animation applied to a sibling

Tags: css

The pattern has two anchors, one of them rotates and becomes blurred when the sibling has :before underlining animation. Can you please suggest what is a possible solution for the current issue?

```css
.sibling {
  position: relative;
  margin: 30px;
}

.sibling:hover:before {
  visibility: hidden;
  transform: scaleX(0);
}

.sibling:before {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #000;
  visibility: visible;
  transform: scaleX(1);
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.rotated {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  margin: 30px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<a class='sibling'>Sibling</a>
<a class='rotated'>Rotated</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `translate3d(0,0,0)` and `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;` to your rotated text. This should work.

```css
.sibling {
  position: relative;
  margin: 30px;
}

.sibling:hover:before {
  visibility: hidden;
  transform: scaleX(0);
}

.sibling:before {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #000;
  visibility: visible;
  transform: scaleX(1);
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.rotated {
  transform: rotate(-90deg) translate3d(0,0,0);
  margin: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
```

```html
<a class='sibling'>Sibling</a>
<a class='rotated'>Rotated</a>
```